# I am trying to run my WAS server from Eclipse and It seems I don't have permission to use my WAS profile. How can I solve it?

Tags: java, websphere, eclipse

[ERROR MESSAGE IN HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkjT0.png)

I am trying to send my first message to a queue in WAS that I created. So, I need to run my WAS server from Eclipse. Is there any way to give permission to myself to use "Custom01" profile and solve this error?

Note: I don't want to create another profile. But if there is no other way it is okay.

I checked the port numbers in eclipse and WAS admin console, I don't think problem result from there.